# Unknown date format Zend Date

Tags: php, zend-framework, date-format

I have to compare two dates, made by the zend object `Zend_Date`. One is stored in a config file as a string. In order to compare the two dates I have to read from the config file the date already in there and then compare it with the `Zend_Date::now()`. The code is the following:

```
 $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/oauth2.ini', 'authorization');
 $date = Zend_Date::now();
 $date_old =new Zend_Date($config->authorization->date, array('date_format'=>'dd/mmm/yyyy HH.mm.ss'));
 $date_old->add($config->authorization->timelapse, $date_old::SECONDS);
 if ($date->isLater($date_old)) {
    //Do what you have to do
 }
```

The error message I’m getting is:

```
 Message: Unknown dateformat type 'array'. Format 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH.mm.ss' must be a valid ISO or PHP date format string.
```

The string I’m giving to the `Zend_Date` object is:

```
 30/gen/2014 13.27.22
```

I thought the date format was right, what am I missing?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of Zend_Date constructor is a "part" string, but you pass an array. So this line should be:

```
$date_old = new Zend_Date($config->authorization->date, 'd/M/Y H.i.s'));
```

Moreover, there's another bug in your code - $date_old::SECONDS is incorrect. Try:

```
$date_old->add($config->authorization->timelapse, Zend_Date::SECOND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date format string isn't proper.

You want it to be `d/M/Y H.i.s` per the documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
d - is the two digit day
M - the three letter abbreviation of the month
Y - the four digit year
H - 24-hour clock with leading zeros
i - minutes with leading zeros
s - seconds
```

You don't need to repeat the characters to specify the number.

so this line:

```
$date_old =new Zend_Date($config->authorization->date, array('date_format'=>'dd/mmm/yyyy  H.mm.ss'));
```

becomes

```
$date_old =new Zend_Date($config->authorization->date, 'd/M/Y H.i.s');
```

Answer (score 1):

As [per the docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Date/Zend_Date_DateObject/Zend_Date.html#method__construct), the second argument for the Zend_Date constructor must be a **STRING**, you're passing in an array. Try

```
$date_old = new Zend_Date($config->authorization->date, 'dd/mmm/yyyy HH.mm.ss')
                                                        ^^^^^---not an array
```